# How to display declared variable in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I'm just wondering if there's a way to display a declared variable in PIG - for test purpose (without UDF)?

So how to display **$DATE**:

```
%declare DATE `date +%s`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your script as a dry run using the following:

```
pig -x local -r my_pig_script.pig
```

Which will output `my_pig_script.pig.substituted` in your working directory. If you look into that file, all variables declared will be replaced with their values. This gives you sort of a "precompile" look at what your job will do before you send it to the cluster.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

The dry run will also help you debug your script and identify any compile errors ahead of an actual run.

Comment: For "predefined" strings it works fine, but when I stored the current date (`date`): 2015-04-28 23:44:59,030 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.PreprocessorContext - Executing command : date 
Just in case of dryrun.

Comment: If I have `test.pig` script containing: `%declare DATE `date +%s`;
STORE $DATE INTO '/dev/stdout';` and call `pig -x local -r test.pig`, I get a file called `test.pig.substituted`. The contents of that file are: `; STORE 1430264051 INTO '/dev/stdout';`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to display the variable without storing it in a file, try the following:

```
%declare DATE `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`;
sh echo $DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

A **STORE** statement writes output to the file system; or, a **DUMP** statement displays output to the screen

```
A = LOAD 'student' USING PigStorage() AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name;
DUMP B;
(John)
(Mary)
(Bill)
(Joe)
```

For More info : https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html